# Test case is leaking async ops on deno

Tags: deno

I downloaded the example app from Drash (https://github.com/drashland/deno-drash)

`$ deno run --allow-run --allow-read --allow-write --allow-net https://deno.land/x/drash/create_app.ts --api`

and try to add a new test, which:

1. will fetch GET /
2. Assert status code and response json

```js
Deno.test("HomeResource - GET /", async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1557", {
    method: "GET",
  });
  assertEquals(response.status, 200);
  assertEquals(
    await response.json(),
    JSON.stringify({
      success: true,
      message: "GET request received.",
    }),
  );
});
```

Here is the error message

```
Server listening: http://localhost:1557
running 5 tests
test HomeResource - GET / ... FAILED (9ms)
test HomeResource - POST / ... ok (2ms)
test HomeResource - PUT / ... ok (2ms)
test HomeResource - DELETE / ... ok (2ms)

Stop the server ... ok (0ms)

failures:

HomeResource - GET /
AssertionError: Test case is leaking async ops.
Before:
  - dispatched: 1
  - completed: 0
After:
  - dispatched: 9
  - completed: 7

Make sure to await all promises returned from Deno APIs before
finishing test case.
    at assert (rt/06_util.js:33:13)
    at asyncOpSanitizer (rt/40_testing.js:44:7)
    at async Object.resourceSanitizer [as fn] (rt/40_testing.js:68:7)
    at async TestRunner.[Symbol.asyncIterator] (rt/40_testing.js:240:13)
    at async Object.runTests (rt/40_testing.js:317:22)

failures:

    HomeResource - GET /

test result: FAILED. 4 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out (15ms)
```

I have tried to cancel the body with
`response.body?.cancel()`, but says that the stream is locked.

Tests: https://github.com/ramonmedeiros/learning_deno/blob/master/tests/resources/home_resource_test.ts

Comment: Deno 1.19 improved the error messages for these types of errors to make them easier to understand, see [here](https://deno.com/blog/v1.19#better-errors-for-ops-and-resource-sanitizers-in-denotest)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The test cases are leaking ops and resources. Maybe Drash is not handling this properly.

These are the resources before and after the fetch request-

```
┌───────┬───────────────┐
│ (idx) │    Values     │
├───────┼───────────────┤
│   0   │    "stdin"    │
│   1   │   "stdout"    │
│   2   │   "stderr"    │
│   3   │ "tcpListener" │
└───────┴───────────────┘
┌───────┬───────────────┐
│ (idx) │    Values     │
├───────┼───────────────┤
│   0   │    "stdin"    │
│   1   │   "stdout"    │
│   2   │   "stderr"    │
│   3   │ "tcpListener" │
│   4   │  "tcpStream"  │
└───────┴───────────────┘
```

These are the ops before and after the fetch request-

```
┌─────────────────────────┬────────┐
│          (idx)          │ Values │
├─────────────────────────┼────────┤
│      opsDispatched      │   5    │
│    opsDispatchedSync    │   4    │
│   opsDispatchedAsync    │   1    │
│ opsDispatchedAsyncUnref │   0    │
│      opsCompleted       │   4    │
│    opsCompletedSync     │   4    │
│    opsCompletedAsync    │   0    │
│ opsCompletedAsyncUnref  │   0    │
│    bytesSentControl     │  121   │
│      bytesSentData      │   46   │
│      bytesReceived      │  418   │
└─────────────────────────┴────────┘
┌─────────────────────────┬────────┐
│          (idx)          │ Values │
├─────────────────────────┼────────┤
│      opsDispatched      │   14   │
│    opsDispatchedSync    │   6    │
│   opsDispatchedAsync    │   8    │
│ opsDispatchedAsyncUnref │   0    │
│      opsCompleted       │   12   │
│    opsCompletedSync     │   6    │
│    opsCompletedAsync    │   6    │
│ opsCompletedAsyncUnref  │   0    │
│    bytesSentControl     │  323   │
│      bytesSentData      │ 73903  │
│      bytesReceived      │  1060  │
└─────────────────────────┴────────┘
```

The `tcpStream` resource is not closed after the test.
See the `opsDispatchedAsync` and `opsCompletedAsync`. All the async ops are not completed.
This is async ops and resources sanitization as mentioned [here](https://deno.land/manual/testing#resource-and-async-op-sanitizers). These are enabled by default but can be disabled by setting `sanitizeResources` and `sanitizeOps` to `false` as done in the last test case -

```
Deno.test({
  name: "\b\b\b\b\b     \nStop the server",
  fn() {
    server.close();
  },
  sanitizeResources: false,
  sanitizeOps: false,
});
```