# How to test deno WebSocket Server?

Tags: typescript, testing, deno

I have written a small WebSocket Server class in Typescript using deno.

Now, I want to test it. Everything works fine when I just run the server and after that close it.

But when I try to connect to the server in the testcase via `new WebSocket("ws://{myserver}")` I get the following error:

> Test case is leaking async ops.

My Code:

```js
Deno.test("run server", (): void => {
    const serverConfig = {
        autoServe: true,
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3045,
    };

    const server = new WSServer(serverConfig);

    console.log(server);

    const conn = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3045");

    conn.send("hello");

    conn.close();

    assertEquals<number>(server.config.port, serverConfig.port);

    assertEquals<boolean>(server.listening, true);

    server.close();
});
```

Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test case is leaking async ops on deno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882609/test-case-is-leaking-async-ops-on-deno)

Comment: Hey, thanks! Yes, first it answered my question, but I have found a good solution, I will post it here for others, who maybe will run into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this problem. I have to wait for the WebSocket connection to open. But when I send something on the connection and the close the connection it won't send the data and I have to close the connection, because else Deno gives me the error that

> Test case is leaking async ops

So I implemented in my server code, that sends an answer to each sent data.

In the working server I will send a confirm message with a unique code.

So for the test case (currently, it doesn't do something with a confirmation message, and listens only for any message from the server) I have now:

```js
Deno.test("run server", async () => {
    const serverConfig = {
        autoServe: true,
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3045,
    };

    const server = new WSServer(serverConfig);

    const conn = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3045");

    const awaitOpen = (connection: WebSocket): Promise<boolean> => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            conn.addEventListener("open", () => {
                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    };

    const awaitResponse = (connection: WebSocket): Promise<string> => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            conn.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                resolve(String(event.data));
            });
        });
    }

    await awaitOpen(conn);

    conn.send("hello");

    const response = await awaitResponse(conn);

    if (response) {
        conn.close();

        server.close();
    }

    assertEquals<number>(server.config.port, serverConfig.port);

    assertEquals<boolean>(server.listening, true);
});
```

I hope, this is helpful for somebody.

Comment: This actually cause AddInUse error when it has multiple test suites or modules. Currently Deno doesn't provide way for setup test environment and global test setup like Jest does.

Answer (score 0):

##### https://deno.land/x/sugar_ws@v0.2.4

##### [SugarWs](https://deno.land/x/sugar_ws@v0.2.4)

You can try this helper to simplify solution for such problems especially in tests.

*This is simple wrapper around WebSocket that was written by me to resolve exactly such problems as you described above. Handle edge socket's state in async way, with promises, to be sure start/finich test etc.*

*So if interesting you may check this module. It plus-minus make the same logic that you provide in your answer.*